# Better MySQL Query Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-execution-plan

I want to get the SUM of QTYs of an item# grouped be months, the query takes too long (15 - 20) seconds to fetch.

-Total rows: 1495873
-Total Fetched rows: 9 - 12

The relation between two tables (`invoice_header` and `invoice_detail`) is (one to many) that the `invoice_header` is the header of an invoice, with only totals. Which is linked to invoice_detail using location ID (`loc_id`) and Invoice number (`invo_no`), as each location has its own serial number. The invoice detail contains the details of each invoice.

Is there's a better way to enhance the performance of that query, here it's:

```
SELECT SUM(invoice_detail.qty) AS qty, Month(invoice_header.date) AS month
FROM invoice_detail
JOIN invoice_header ON invoice_detail.invo_no = invoice_header.invo_no
AND  invoice_detail.loc_id = invoice_header.loc_id
WHERE invoice_detail.item_id = {$itemId}
GROUP BY Month(invoice_header.date)
ORDER BY Month(invoice_header.date)
```

EXPLAIN:

[image: explain]

invoice_header table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice_header` (
 `invo_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `invo_no` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `invo_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `time` time NOT NULL,
 `cust_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `loc_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `cash_man_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sales_man_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ref_invo_no` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `total_amount` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
 `tax` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
 `discount_amount` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
 `net_value` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
 `split` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
 `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_type_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `comments` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`invo_no`,`loc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20286 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image: invoice_header table structure:]

invoice_detail table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice_detail` (
 `invo_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `loc_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `item_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `size_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `rtp` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
 `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`invo_no`,`loc_id`,`serial`),
 KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
 KEY `size_id` (`size_id`),
 KEY `invo_no` (`invo_no`),
 KEY `serial` (`serial`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image: invoice_detail table structure:]

Comment: 1. Post schema for every table from the query 2. `EXPLAIN` 3. Statistics (total rows, filtered rows, indexes cardinality, definition for "too long", etc...)

Comment: Ok @zerkms, will update the post with the structure of the 2 table.

Comment: use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead, so that it included everything, like indexes. Also - **all 3** items are **required** to help you. It's not like I'm kidding you and asking some irrelevant info, but essentials to help you.

Comment: @zerkms, I just update it now again with requirement.

Comment: please read the first comment once again. #2 and #3 are still missing

Comment: The "EXPLAIN" that zerkms refers to is you run your query but put the word "EXPLAIN" just before the SELECT and mysql will output a little mini-report that can help identify the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks @user1269942, just update it now.

Comment: @zerkms, I think I made all points now.

Answer (score 1):

According to see the result of explain `invoice_header` can not use any multiple index.

You could create index on field `invo_no` on `invoice_header` Table.

Comment: The result of explain for table "invoice_header" is null so . It searches to all of rows that  exists inside  "invoice_header" table.because it has only one key that is the combination of `invo_no`,`loc_id`. for "ON invoice_detail.invo_no = invoice_header.invo_no" condition you can create index on field invoice_header.invo_no for searching on less rows inside nested loop of join.

Answer (score 1):

How long does it take by following SQL?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM invoice_detail
WHERE invoice_detail.item_id = {$itemId}
```

If this SQL takes 15-20 seconds, you should add an index on field item_id on inovice_detail table.

The invoice_header already had the primary key on the join columns of invo_no and loc_id, so you don't need add other indexes on invoice_header table.  But if you add an index on fields invo_no, loc_id and date, that may enhance a little performance by only index scan.

Comment: your query took just 3 seconds to run, while after adding indexes to invo_no, loc_id and date in "invoice_header" and index "item_id" in "invoice_detail" now the main query is taking 8-10 seconds. Any suggestions to improve it more?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a few indexes on some columns: invo_no, loc_id, item_id, date.

based on your explain, your query is scanning all rows in invoice_header.  Index the columns that make the join...  invo_no, loc_id

Comment: @CairoCoder: the thing is - you either follow the "procedure" that helps everyone around to optimize their databases, or follow the random things and hope they will randomly work for you. It's up to you which path to follow.